# OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

In order to ensure that passwords are always stored, hashed and salted in the database, I decided to use a descriptor which will automatically hash the password when one is provided, e.g user.password = "jinja125".

Here is my code

```
from random import SystemRandom
from backports.pbkdf2 import pbkdf2_hmac, compare_digest

# ...snip...    

@password.setter
def password(self, value):
    # When a user is first created, give them a salt
    if self._salt is None:
        self._salt = bytes(SystemRandom().getrandbits(128))
    self._password = self._hash_password(value)
```

However when I try to run some tests, I get this error.

```
File "C:\Users\User\flask-python\site-tracker\app\users\models.py", line 34, in password
    self._salt = bytes(random.SystemRandom().getrandbits(simple_bit_counts))
OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer
```

How can I best fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.getrandbits):

> random.getrandbits(k)
>   Returns a python long int with **k random bits**.

Here `k==128` so `1<<128`

check the size value you're trying to create a `bytes` array from (for instance):

```
>>> random.SystemRandom().getrandbits(128)
135192632488754159854542557748438253357
```

That's way too big for array indexing, not to mention the memory. You may want to reduce drastically your value. I suppose you meant `2**7` (7-bit random) not `1<<128`

now if you wanted to generate 128 random *bytes*, you'd do that instead:

```
>>> bytes(random.randrange(0,255) for _ in range(128))
b'\xc9\x8fC\t\xe0\xc8\x8a5\xe4\xafb\xb5c.\x91\xea\x9aqUL\x11\x8d\xe4\xe3W\x87\xecM\xf8K\xa8\xf8\xbb\xb5 \x14H\xda\x1d]L\x13[n*\x87W\xd8\x90v\xfd\x8cQ\xdcY\xe4^\x95h8\xdc\'\x8e\xcb:\xea\xfbF\xf1zh8\xf63\x18WeV\xc6)\xce\xf9*w>\x83e\x0b#"\xf2\x97\xcf\xc2!\xddj\xb2\xbePl\xa2\r\xa7T\x8f\x14\x13\xa4\x1c\xeax\xacMJ2\x88A,\x11\xdev\xe1\xf8\x9b\x12\xd9c'
```

no need to call `getrandbits` for that. As Amadan noted, maybe you want 128 bits, not bytes, so make that `range(16)` instead. Well, now that you know, you can adjust to your actual needs.

Comment: He probably meant `128`, but misused `bytes` - I think he wanted b'????????????????', a sixteen-byte string, not a `135192632488754159854542557748438253357`-length array.

Comment: yes, I don't know what the user wanted exactly, but there's a wrong magnitude order :)...

Comment: This also works, in Python3: `SystemRandom().getrandbits(128).to_bytes(16, 'little')`, to stay a bit close to OP's initial idea. (Also note, 128 random _bits_ is _16_ random bytes, not 128)

Comment: @Amadan true, and true again. You could post an answer about that, mind. I'm not going to put that in my answer since I wasn't aware of that feature.